# present a UIviewcontroller programmatically from UINavigationController with Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

**My question**: How can I switch between viewcontrollers with 1 `rootNavigationController` in code, while maintaining customization I set in Storyboard and data that I load up in my viewcontrollers?

Currently I am implementing [REMenu](https://github.com/romaonthego/REMenu), which provides a simple dropdown tableview to change views with. When one of those cells is pressed in the dropdown, I want to switch my view. For example, if I press "Home", I want to go to my `MasterViewController`  The method to switch views is called from within `rootnavigationcontroller.m`, and looks like the following:

```
REMenuItem *homeItem = [[REMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home"
                                                subtitle:@"Return to Home Screen"
                                                   image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon_Home"]
                                        highlightedImage:nil
                                                  action:^(REMenuItem *item) {

                                                      UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

                                                      UINavigationController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myNewTableView"];

                                                 //     vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
                                                      [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
                                                  }];
```

Clearly, however, something is wrong with this implementation, because it ignores the UI Customization I made in Storyboard, as well as a datacontroller I invoke in `MasterViewController.m` Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A couple of things...  Do you realize that `[[MasterViewController alloc] init]` creates a new controller with all it's own new instance data? Assuming you do and that you want a new one, then you should get it from the storyboard rather than just calling `init`.  (E.g. `- (id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier`)

Comment: @PhillipMills would you mind taking a look at my revised code? I'm able to transition the view now, however it doesn't maintain my navigation controller (in other words there's no more nav bar at the top). Does it make sense for me to create a new navigation controller for each new stack of views? For example, if I want to switch from my main tableviewcontroller to a new tableview controller showing a users profile, does it make sense to create an entirely new navigation controller??